# Is it possible to force say, `gcc`, to produce identical binaries for identical pieces of source code in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, flags

Say one has a C program like the following:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I have two files with the source code above, one with 'c' extension, another with 'cpp'. I compile them as C and C++ programs, respectively. **The binaries are different**. I thought C++ was a "zero overhead" language? :-) What I am trying to find is compiler flags for two different setups where the resulting binaries are the same. Preferably some kind language standard, not GCC extensions of any kind.

Comment: how about using extern "C" {} ? And C++ isn't zero overhead language.

Comment: The overhead of C++ isn't zero, it's just that generally the rule "if you don't use it, you don't pay for it" is applied. C and C++ compilers aren't the same thing, so it's not surprising you'd end up with different binaries.

Answer (score 6):

> **The binaries are different.**

*How* are they different?

GCC will embed information into the file about the original source filenames and options used, so will always have *some* differences for different filenames even of the content is identical.

If I compile your program as C and C++ the only difference I see is that the C++ version is linked to `libstdc++`, which happens automatically when using `g++` to link.  If I instead use  `gcc` to link then the binaries are almost identical.

N.B. you can use `gcc` to compile C++ programs, the `gcc` and `g++` binaries are just drivers that look at the filename and invoke the correct compiler binary (`cc1` for C, `cc1plus` for C++) to do the actual compilation. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html for more details.

This shows that for identical source code the only difference in the assembler output is the string giving the original filenames, and the object files are the same size:

```
$ cat f.c
cat: f.c: No such file or directory
$ rm f.c
$ cat > f.c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
$ ln -s f.c f.cc
$ gcc f.c -S -o f.c.s
$ g++ f.cc -S -o f.cxx.s
$ diff f.c*.s
--- f.c.s       2012-08-26 13:45:58.109711329 +0100
+++ f.cxx.s     2012-08-26 13:46:00.482634256 +0100
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-       .file   "f.c"
+       .file   "f.cc"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
$ gcc f.c -c -o f.c.o
$ g++ f.cc -c -o f.cxx.o
$ ls -l f.c*.o
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jwakely users 1240 Aug 26 13:46 f.c.o
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jwakely users 1240 Aug 26 13:46 f.cxx.o
```

And in the final executable the difference comes from how it's linked, whether the C++ standard library is linked to or not:

```
$ gcc f.c.o -o a.c.out
$ gcc f.cxx.o -o a.cxx.out
$ g++ f.cxx.o -o a.cxx.libstdcxx.out
$ ls -l a.c*.out
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 jwakely users 6323 Aug 26 13:48 a.c.out
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 jwakely users 6468 Aug 26 13:48 a.cxx.libstdcxx.out
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 jwakely users 6324 Aug 26 13:48 a.cxx.out
```

If you don't need the C++ standard library, don't link to it.

Comment: There is a problem with not linking with standard library - it is part of the language, isn't it? I am not interested in hacking some weird compilation profile. I just wish that say if I don't use exceptions then I don't want any stub code in my binary.

Comment: In typical implementations some features of the language are provided by the compiler, some are provided by an additional library that must be linked to. If you don't need the latter features, don't link to the library. It's irrelevant that the features are part of the language, if you don't use them then you don't need to link to the library providing them.

Answer (score 2):

This is just another version of "how short is my empty main" false problem.

There are part of "infrastructure" that carries the startup and ending code as well as standard library global objects that must be linked in any case, whatever the program actually is.

Measuring an empty main program, is in fact measuring the size of the startup/ending code. That must be different in C and C++ since C++ has much more things to do to prepare to call main than C actually has to do.

I  don't know what you mean by "zero overhead language". Neither C and C++ are. They both minimize the overhead in their respective domains.
The only zero overhead language is - by definition - the native machine code.

Comment: There is no reason an empty program should need more startup code in C++, it's an empty program, there are no globals or constructors to run.

Comment: The core library code is linked (not compiled by you) and doesn't know if there are or not global constructors to call. It must in any case prepare the hooks to do that. The fact you don't use them doesn't make them to disappear.

Comment: ??? We are saying the same thing: the main.c / main.cpp translate the same. the executable are different because they link a different library.

Comment: They only link a different library because the linker is called with `-lstdc++` not because it's required or because "C++ has much more things to do to prepare to call main than C actually has to do" as you claimed.

Comment: hummm... not properly: the point is that if you don't link the c++ library, you are anymore able to properly dismiss whatever static object. And that is a prerequisite of C++ respect of C. A C++ program with an emmpty main can do things. A C program not.   Of course, in this particular case, "castrated C++" works like C, but whatever C++ program that make sense cannot run properly in that way.  C++ is also its library (is par of the same language spec.) Doing without it is doing something that is not C++ anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they are different, even simple things like function names are handled differently by c and c++.
`void foo()` in c is simply `foo` in c++ that name gets mangled since the c version does not contain enough information to deal with multiple foo functions with different parameter lists like `void foo(int)`.

Then there are different standard libraries which are linked in by default since they are used by most c/c++ programs (for your zero overhead claim this can be disabled ).

Most important are different rules concerning well defined behavior, c++ is not a superset of c and while there is a large amount of overlap there are many cases where they differ. See for example `sizeof('a')` in c and c++.

Conclusion: c and c++ compilers producing identical binaries from identical source code while possible is extremely unlikely to happen.

Comment: I think you mean "functions" not "methods"